# Trying to dereference `&`-pointer

Tags: algorithm, pointers, rust

I am trying to write a naif implementation of kmeans in Rust for learning purposes. One of the steps is as follows: I have a collection of points `xs` and another collection of points `centroids`. I want to group the `xs` based on the nearest neighbour among the centroids. That is, two points belong to the same group if they have a common nearest neighbour.

For instance in Scala this would look like

```
xs groupBy { x => closest(x, centroids) } values
```

Not finding a `groupBy` method in the standard library, I tried to write it like follows (assume `Point` and `closest` are defined):

```
fn clusters(xs: & Vec<Point>, centroids: & Vec<Point>) -> Vec<Vec<Point>> {
  let mut groups: TreeMap<Point, Vec<Point>> = TreeMap::new();

  // for x in xs.iter() {
  //   let y = closest(*x, centroids);
  //   match groups.find(&y) {
  //     Some(mut val) => val.push(*x),
  //     None => {
  //       groups.insert(y, vec![*x]);
  //     },
  //   }
  // }

  let result: Vec<Vec<Point>> = groups.values().map(|x| *x).collect();
  result
}
```

I have commented the central part, because I already have problems creating a `TreeMap<Point, Vec<Point>>` and returning its values as a `Vec<Vec<Point>>`. There is a method `values` on TreeMap, which returns an iterator of type `Map<...>`. I have tried:

- returning the iterator directly, but Rust complains that then I have to add a lifetime specifier and I am not sure which one to use
- collect it into a `Vec`. The problem is that the elements of the iterator are actually pointers to `Vec<Point>`, so I have to do something like `let result: Vec<& Vec<Point>> = groups.values().collect();`. Again, Rust will not let me return those pointers, because they live too short
- dereferencing all those pointers, like the above. I think this is the right way to go, but Rust tells me `error: cannot move out of dereference of &-pointer`

What is the correct way to return the values of that map?

Also, if I decomment the central part, Rust prevents me from doing `groups.insert(y, vec![*x]);` because `groups` is locally borrowed as an immutable reference in the pattern matching. How would I go fixing this?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is impossible now to write the second part (with conditional insert) cleanly. It is a known problem and there are proposals to solve it; [one of them](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/396) was submitted just today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first problem is that values() returns an object that provides immutable projection into the TreeMap but you are trying to move the data out of it in the map call.

Two possible solution are:
1) You create copy of the vector. This is however expensive operation.

```
let result: Vec<Vec<Point>> = groups.values().map(|x| x.clone()).collect();
```

2) You use into_iter() method that consumes the treemap and you are free to move data out of it.

```
let result: Vec<Vec<Point>> = groups.into_iter().map(|(p, v)| v).collect();
```

Then, there are two problems in the commented code.

First, you have to get mutable reference to found item so you must call find_mut() instead of find().

Second, in the None branch you are trying to insert into already borrowed treemap (via result of the find()/find_mut() call). Rust wont let you. Currently, the only option is to defer the insert after the match block:

```
  let should_insert = match groups.find_mut(&y) {
      Some(mut val) => {
        val.push(*x);
        false
      }
      None => {
          true
      },
  };
  if should_insert {
      groups.insert(y, vec![*x]);
  }
```

EDIT: There is a better way to this in newer versions of Rust:

```
use std::collections::btree_map::Entry;
match groups.entry(&y) {
    Entry::Occupied(mut view) => { val.get_mut().push(*x); }
    Entry::Vaccant(view) => { view.insert(vec![*x]); }
};
```

Comment: I'd suggest writing `(p, v)` as `(_, v)` to make it explicit that `p` is ignored. Rust should emit warning on this, BTW. This is a minor style issue, though, otherwise the answer is great.

Answer (score 4):

> returning the iterator directly, but Rust complains that then I have to add a lifetime specifier and I am not sure which one to use

The borrow checker saved you from a use-after-free error in this case. Since you create the treemap locally in a function and don't move it anywhere else, its elements automatically get destroyed once the function is done. So, it's actually a good thing that the Rust compiler didn't let you return an iterator to a data structure that will cease to exist right after the function returns.

> dereferencing all those pointers, like the above. I think this is the right way to go, but Rust tells me error: cannot move out of dereference of &-pointer

Right. The situation is similar to this one:

```
let mut mystrings = vec!["hello".to_string(), "world".to_string()];
let x = *mystrings.get(0);
```

Here, you get the same error because you are not allowed to move the first string out of the vector like this. Keep in mind that moving is destructive. This means, that the source will be invalid. But you don't really want to have a vector where the first object is in some kind of invalid state. This is why Rust does not let you move thigns out of references. You could call `clone`

```
let x = mystrings.get(0).clone();
```

but that's probably also not what you want. Cloning vectors and strings is expensive. But you can use `replace` like this:

```
let mut mystrings = vec!["hello".to_string(), "world".to_string()];
let x = ::std::mem::replace(mystrings.get_mut(0), String::new());
```

This moves the string from the vector into x while moving an empty string into the vector as the replacement. This way, the String object in the vector stays valid. Something like this works with vectors, too.

Another way of moving things out of a collection is a "move iterator" like PEPP suggested. He beat me to it.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I have accepted PEPP's answers, as it solves directly the problem at hand, but your comments are very helpful.

Comment: @Andrea: No problem. I didn't feel like repeating what PEPP already wrote and stopped. But I'm glad that you find what I wrote so far useful. That's why I didn't delete it.